# Simple Text-Based Report MS SQL Server 2008 using PRINT

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services

I am nearly finished with my first assignment but the last question has me stumped.

It asks:

> Produce a faulty product **report** that displays the product returned on the 11/07/2010 due to Damaged Exterior

The expected output for this is:

> FAULTY PRODUCT REPORT
>
> --------------------------------------
>
> Product Name: Desk
>
> Customer Name: Simon, Kernel
>
> Reason: Damaged Exterior
>
> (1 rows(s) affected)
>
> ---END OF REPORT---

I found out about SQL `PRINT` now I seem to nearly have it all down to a T:

```
DECLARE @ProductName varchar(30)
SET @ProductName =(SELECT MIN(Products.ProductName) FROM Products)

DECLARE @CustomerName varchar(75)
SET @CustomerName =(SELECT MIN(Customers.FirstName+', '+Customers.Surname) 
FROM Customers,CustomerReturns,Products
WHERE CustomerReturns.ReturnDate='2012/07/11'
AND Products.ProductID=CustomerReturns.ProductID
AND Customers.CustomerID=CustomerReturns.CustomerID)

DECLARE @Reason varchar(30)
SET @Reason =(SELECT MIN(CustomerReturns.Reason) 
FROM CustomerReturns,Products,Customers
WHERE CustomerReturns.Reason='Damaged Exterior')

PRINT 'FAULTY PRODUCT REPORT';
PRINT '';
PRINT '---------------------';
PRINT 'Product Name: '+@ProductName;
PRINT 'Customer Name: '+@CustomerName;
PRINT 'Reason: '+@Reason;
PRINT '';
PRINT '---END OF REPORT---';
```

And my output:

> FAULTY PRODUCT REPORT
>
> --------------------------------------
>
> Product Name: Desk
>
> Customer Name: Simon, Kernel
>
> Reason: Damaged Exterior
>
> ---END OF REPORT---

As you can see I am still missing the:

> (1 rows(s) affected)

How would i make this appear without ofcourse cheating and just printing it? (because then it will stay thay way no matter how many results get returned)

EDIT:

I found doing this: `SELECT @ProductName...` produces the 1row(s) affected, is this correct?:

```
PRINT 'FAULTY PRODUCT REPORT';
PRINT '';
PRINT '---------------------';
PRINT 'Product Name: '+@ProductName;
PRINT 'Customer Name: '+@CustomerName;
PRINT 'Reason: '+@Reason;
SELECT @ProductName,@CustomerName,@Reason
PRINT '';
PRINT '---END OF REPORT---';
```

EIDT2:

Changed it to this:

```
DECLARE @PName varchar(35)
DECLARE @CName varchar(75)
DECLARE @RName varchar(75)
SELECT @PName=Products.ProductName,
 @CName=Customers.FirstName+', '+Customers.Surname ,
 @RName=CustomerReturns.Reason

FROM Products,Customers,CustomerReturns

WHERE CustomerReturns.ReturnDate='2012/09/28'
AND CustomerReturns.Reason='Damaged Exterior'
AND Products.ProductID=CustomerReturns.ProductID
AND Customers.CustomerID=CustomerReturns.CustomerID
PRINT @PName
PRINT @CName
PRINT @RName
```

but still not affected rows thingy

Any help  is appreciated thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at using the `@@ROWCOUNT` function after your query.  This function returns the number of rows affected by the last statement. [Read more about it here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187316.aspx)

Using your second edit above, you could do:

```
DECLARE @PName varchar(35) 
DECLARE @CName varchar(75) 
DECLARE @RName varchar(75)
DECLARE @rowCount int 
SELECT @PName=Products.ProductName, 
 @CName=Customers.FirstName+', '+Customers.Surname , 
 @RName=CustomerReturns.Reason 

FROM Products,Customers,CustomerReturns 

WHERE CustomerReturns.ReturnDate='2012/09/28' 
AND CustomerReturns.Reason='Damaged Exterior' 
AND Products.ProductID=CustomerReturns.ProductID 
AND Customers.CustomerID=CustomerReturns.CustomerID

SET @rowCount = @@ROWCOUNT

PRINT @PName 
PRINT @CName 
PRINT @RName 
--Use @rowCount in your report.
```

Note that you have to obtain the row count immediately after you execute the query. This way, no matter how many rows you get, you'll have the right number - avoiding the "cheat" scenario you mentioned.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you this looks more like what i'd be needing. You the best :P

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT`, `UPDATE`, `INSERT` and `DELETE` all use the Messages tab to output the number of rows affected by the operation. (The `NOCOUNT` flag may affect this, but I haven't done any research to back this up).

You've already identified that a `SELECT` statement is one way for the `(1 rows(s) affected)` text output to appear; however, there's more than one way to generate that output.

Your current query seems to fit the majority of what the assignment asks for - this might be a good time to take it to your instructor and ask for clarification about what they want.

Comment: As I mentioned originally: the `(1 rows(s) affected)` line is a standard output used by SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE, etc. 

The problem is that you're working backwards from the solution text and trying to figure out how to produce the line `(1 rows(s) affected)`. Since there's multiple ways to get that line, the only way to really resolve your question is to ask someone who's seen the original query, like your instructor.

Comment: Thank you I will mark this as solved/ the answer if no other answer of help comes